# Actual colors in MacOS Terminal don't match their values in Preferences

Tags: macos, terminal, colors, themes, ansi-colors

I am trying to build a Terminal theme in MacOS. The colors that are actually being displayed are slightly different from the hex colors I am setting. For example:

[image]

I am setting the background color to #292D3E here. But when I sample the color from the actual background, it is #24293B.

[image]

Why is this happening? It seems to do it with most of the colors. I suspect it has to do with Terminal only being able to use a limited palette? But I'm wondering why it would still allow me to enter it, and why it would still show the pasted value and not change it to the allowed value after I saved it if that were the case.

Comment: Is there transparency or translucency on the terminal background?

Comment: Nope, what you see above is exactly what is set.

Comment: same problem. Some are correctly interpreted but some other aren't.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/29487/is-it-possible-to-disable-terminals-automatic-tweaking-of-colors-in-lion

Answer (score 2):

Terminal.app's Colors use XTERM-256 color Palette. This means it has to convert any RGB to 1 of 256 colors (0-255). They will look different. Terminal.app doesn't support true color's yet but surprising they do support transparency. It's best to lookup the color you want from XTERM-256 and then manually pick which colors you want from there. You can find the RGB value's online.
https://www.ditig.com/256-colors-cheat-sheet